# Facing issue while running working vuejs laravel project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-8

npm run dev
After this error appear
INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error

This relative module was not found:

**./src/main.js in multi ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8083/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js**

Comment: Can you provide full error message ?

Comment: This is full error

Comment: > npm run serve


> vue-material-dashboard-pro@1.4.0 serve /home/afzal/example-app
> vue-cli-service serve --open

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                       7:18:59 PM

This relative module was not found:

* ./src/main.js in multi ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8083/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

Comment: Check if port 8083 is already open or change to another one

Comment: `This relative module was not found: * ./src/main.js` this is error

Comment: The port 8083 is not

Comment: Is not open. Yes ./src/main.js is not found